# Разъясните по свойству text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: css, вёрстка

Добрый день, не до конца понял свойство

```
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

оно работает только для текста в одну линию в паре со свойством

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

нужно сделать эффект обрезания текста красиво, градиент не подойдет может кто знает это сделать с эффектом многоточия?

Comment: ну во первых что значит в вашем понимании "красиво"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-on-multiline-text

Answer (score 1):

```css
.text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<div class="text">text text text text text text text text text</div>
```

[источник](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=909&rub=2)

Comment: Вот я об этом и спрашивал, можно сделать то же самое только для нескольких строк текста, скажем в блок помещается 3 строки и последняя заканчивается многоточием?

Comment: Ну если только применить JavaScript

Comment: @Constantine Shibaev, свойство ellipsis работает только для одной строки текста. Средствами css подобное обрезание текста из нескольких строк не сделать

Comment: @mJeevas Я нашел способ сделать это для нескольких строк, правда это работает только для хрома вот таким куском кода display: -webkit-box; -webkit-line-clamp: 4; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;