# Не работает text-overflow: ellipsis; в ячейке таблицы

Tags: css, overflow

Подскажите, почему фраза "Сайты с неопределенным наполнением" в таблице не сокращается при недостатке места?
И возможно ли это реализовать только силами css ?

https://github.com/anna-popova/TestForZecurion

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почитай про truncate

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562396/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83-text-overflow-ellipsis?rq=1

Comment: Потому что оно впритык, если добавите этому элементу с текстом ограничение, допустим `max-width: calc(100% - 10px)`, то появятся многоточие.